# "Open with" in VirtualBox Seamless mode

Tags: virtualbox, microsoft-office

I would like to be able to use Excel as my default application for opening .xls and xlsx files using VirtualBox seamless mode. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible. Just look at this solution: https://bbruno5.blogspot.com/?view=classic

Comment: We do not like link-only answers here.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/712192)